# exclude ~$ names from archiving by 7za

Tags: backup, 7za

Im trying exclude some temp files from archive, but

```
-x!*\~$*
```

not working. Can you fix me, please?

Full command, which I use:

```
7za a -ssw -mx9 -xr!?git\* -x!*\~$* "...\asdasd.7z"  "C:\...\folder"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `-xr` rather than just `-x` to tell `7z` that the excluded files are in a subdirectory. You have taken `-xr` for the `git` tree.

If `delayed expansion` of environment variables is active in your script, you have to [escape](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.Escape) the `!`. Write `^^!` instead.

Example:

```
7z a -r -ssw -mx9 -xr!"~$*" c:\target\xxx.7z c:\myfolder\*.*
```

Comment: I have unnecessary files from
    ||7za a -ssw -mx9 -x!*\~$* "asdasd.7z" "folder"||
in archive.
It's temporary msword files..
||Compressing  some_folder\some\~$some_file.docx||
How exclude it?

Comment: See my example above. I am using 7z.exe rather than 7za.exe. Note the extra quotes and the wildcards.

Comment: Its working, thx